# How to get parameters from a url and use it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to create a checkout flow for my app in which i get the products from the shopping as a url and i take the parameters from the url and add form parameters and together form another url and send it to a php file where i save the datas received. I just wanted to know whether the way i am doing it is correct or not. If not can you please help me by correcting it.

Here is the **checkout.js**

```
 function formload() {
 $('form').submit(function(event) {

    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    $('.help-block').remove(); 
    var formData = {
        'fname'             : $('input[name=fname]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'phone'             : $('input[name=phone]').val(),
        'address'           : $('input[name=address]').val(),
        'zip'               : $('input[name=zip]').val(),
        'Product'           : location.search.substring(1)
    };
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'GET',
        url         : 'http://localhost/donotdel/process.php',
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json',
        encode      : true
    })
        .done(function(data) {

            console.log(data); 

            if ( ! data.success) {

                if (data.errors.fname) {
                    $('#fname-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#fname-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>');
                }

                if (data.errors.email) {
                    $('#email-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>');
                }

                if (data.errors.phone) {
                    $('#telephone-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#telephone-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>');
                }

                if (data.errors.address) {
                    $('#address-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#address-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>');
                }

                if (data.errors.zip) {
                    $('#Zip-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#Zip-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>');
                }

                if (data.errors.products) {
                    $('#Product-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#Product-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>');
                }

            } else {

                $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

                window.location = 'http://www.dekhodaily.com';

            }
        })

        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    event.preventDefault();
   });
  }
```

so my doubt is can i use

```
'Product'           : location.search.substring(1)
```

for getting the product parameter from the url and add along with the form data and send like i have done in the code.

Comment: I'm not quit sure why you are passing the urls to your php script. Normally you would have product table and just pass the product id to your script

Comment: i am passing to a php file as i have to save all the product data and the data in the database

Answer (score 1):

I think **YES**... You are doing it right but to be more elegant and efficient way for multipurpose use small function below helps you to get `parameters` from `url`

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

an say now your url is

<kbd>**`http://dummy.com/?product=someId&somemoreDetail=somethingelse`**</kbd>

You can fetch it as below:

```
var pid = getUrlParameter('product');
var somedetail = getUrlParameter('somemoreDetail');
```

and below is how you can integrate in your code:

Assuming your url to be **<kbd>`https://www.something.com?product=someID`</kbd>**

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    $('.help-block').remove(); 

    var prod=getUrlParameter('product');
    //prod will now have the value someID
    var formData = {
        'fname'             : $('input[name=fname]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'phone'             : $('input[name=phone]').val(),
        'address'           : $('input[name=address]').val(),
        'zip'               : $('input[name=zip]').val(),
        'Product'           : prod
    };

    //Other ajax codes
});
```

**<kbd>[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903119/2065039)</kbd>**